# Is it possible to have a model validator change depending on another variable?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I was thinking something like this:

```
[(if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(b)), ErrorMessage = "Both 'a' and 'b' cannot be null")]
string a;

[(if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(b)), ErrorMessage = "Both 'a' and 'b' cannot be null")]
string b;
```

*Not exactly written like like this but I think this way it best describes the situation*

Comment: model validator change? what kind of change? What is the meaning of attributes you provided?

Comment: Did you tried combination of `[Required]` and `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false)]` for both `a` & `b` model properties? If you cannot use the `DisplayFormat` attribute, you need to create a custom attribute based on `RequiredAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation)? You can easily create custom validators like what you want with it and also, there are some predefined validators exist.

What you want in FluentValidation is [When/Unless](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#conditions) condition :

```
RuleFor(m => m.FirstName).NotEmpty().When(m => string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.LastName));
```

or

```
RuleFor(m => m.LastName).NotEmpty().Unless(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.FirstName));
```

If you want Attribute Validators you can take a look at [FoolProof](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=foolproof) to get the idea behind that.